# Run go simple app with Jetbrains GoLand IDE

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I've just started learning GO. Ok, I've some weird issue and did not figure out how to fix it.
I have 2 go file. one is main.go and second is state.go and they are both in same package called main.
In state.go file I defined simple function printHello, which then I'm calling it in main.go.

state.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printHello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

main.go

```
package main

func main()  {
    printHello()
}
```

When I run it in cmd with command: go run main.go state.go it works fine, but in GoLand IDE it didn't. I tried to build it changed Run Kind to Directory, but without success. Also attached image for more clarification
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `main.go` opened in the editor.

Click on the green arrow at the left side of main function.

It will run and creates a run configuration that you can customize.

Comment: As you see at image, I cam modify configuration. But don't know how to run state.go file alongside with main.go

Comment: What do you mean along side? if they are in the same folder and package... The main is calling a function in state.go... it should run the function ...

Comment: I should create module as well, I created it and then I was able to run app successfully

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run the `state.go`; just run `main.go`. The Goland IDE will take care of it since they are in the same package (`main`).